# Is it possible to name the threads used by System.Diagnostics.Process()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running a Process, and getting events for stdout and stderr data.

It seems to be using three threads for this, all called

```
'<No Name>'
```

Is it possible for me to give these threads more descriptive names?

**Update**

The process is running "cmd", "/c " + command, and collecting and displaying stdout and stderr, so I have no direct access to the code being run

The process is being created with the following code

```
       System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

        proc.Exited += new EventHandler(proc_Exited);
        proc.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_ErrorDataReceived);
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Comment: You can name *your own* threads; but I assume you want to give names to the threads outside your control?

Comment: Sort of. They are created when I call Process.Start(), but I can't find a way of giving them names

Comment: What does this process do? Do you the code the process is running?

Comment: Do you mean you're creating the process with Process.Start?  If not can you show how you're invoking it?

Comment: You can, but it doesn't work well enough.  The only way to get a reference to the Thread object is from Thread.CurrentThread.  In the callback, so that's too late.  And you can't un-name it before it is returned to the pool.